# Why don't we use AC coupling caps for USB 2.0

Tags: microcontroller, capacitor, usb, signal-integrity

[image]I see we have a requirement for AC caps on USB 3.0 running at 5 Gbps. But why not at USB 2.0 480 Mbps?

My question is about why is there  need for AC coupling caps on 3.0? Whereas none on USb 2.0

I have seen this typical architecture of USb 3.0 with AC caps on TX side. Picture taken from one of the app notes i cam across https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND9116-D.PDF

Comment: Can you list the requirment and where you found it?

Comment: @VoltageSpike, USB3 signal lines do use AC decoupling, read specifications.

Comment: @Ale..chenski I'm not questioning the OP, I think it would be great if the OP could expand the answer so it isn't flagged by the system and also provide future readers with information on the requirment.

Comment: @VoltageSpike, yes, I agree, the OP didn't reveal what problem he/she would like to solve by introducing AC decoupling into USB2.0 signaling protocol.

Comment: My thinking is USB 3.0 has a much more tight impedance control requirement to increase it's bandwidth... and needs caps to help it achieve that is that right?

Comment: @VolatgeSpike 
I want to understand why cant we use AC caps on USb 2.0? USB 3.0 uses sort of a SERDES technology, is that the reason why we use AC caps on 3.0 but not on 2.0

Comment: @Ale..chenski I'm not trying to add AC caps on USb 2.0. I'm only trying to understand the fundamentals on why we use caps on 3.0 but not on 2.0. Hope that helps.

Comment: @learningninja in which way does my answer not answer that question?

Comment: @learningninja please provide a reference for the image (plagerisim is not good) thanks

Answer (score 3):

USB3.0 Super Speed goes over fundamentally different lines than the USB2.0 HighSpeed signal; these are literally different cables inside your USB cable assembly!

USB2.0 has a different kind of data modulation, and DC resistance is used to sense properties of the line, and there's not as strict balance control.

I've been asked to elaborate: USB2 uses differential signaling on its D+/D- lines – but not really. There's a third state where both lines are pulled in the same direction (used as comma in framing, in the end), and that means there is, on average, a direct current flowing in *one* direction – meaning that your coupling caps would very soon be full charged and you'd need to add a discharge functionality to USB. That wouldn't then be USB.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind elaborating a little more on above points? How does data modulation or dc resistance on 2.0 vs 3.0 affect the decision on need for having AC caps?

Comment: @learningninja  USB2 signaling is not fully differential. Some bus states use DC levels (like single-ended zero EOP or SUSPEND state), so AC de-coupling won't work.